# What is needed to send a POJO with Camel's ProducerTemplate#sendBody()

Tags: apache-camel, javabeans, ognl

I am trying to send a POJO using ProducerTemplate#sendBody(), but I get the following error:

```
org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException: Failed to invoke 
  method: [searchId] on app.FsiRequest due to: 
  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Key: searchId not found in bean: 
  app.FsiRequest@5c2d65cf of type: app.FsiRequest using OGNL path [[searchId]]

    at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression.evaluate(BeanExpression.java:119) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression.evaluate(BeanExpression.java:135) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.language.ExpressionDefinition.evaluate(ExpressionDefinition.java:127) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.language.ExpressionDefinition.evaluate(ExpressionDefinition.java:119) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.camel.builder.ExpressionBuilder$40.evaluate(ExpressionBuilder.java:1004) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ExpressionAdapter.evaluate(ExpressionAdapter.java:36) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.camel.builder.SimpleBuilder.evaluate(SimpleBuilder.java:92) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
```

The class I'm sending (simplified):

```
public class FsiRequest {
    public String getSearchId() {
        return searchId;
    }

    public void setSearchId(String searchId) {
        this.searchId = searchId;
    }

    private String searchId;

    public FsiRequest(Map<String, String> request) {
        searchId = request.get("searchId");
    }
}
```

Here's my invocation:

```
private final ForkJoinPool routeExecutorPool = new ForkJoinPool(1024);

@Override
public void configure() {
    from("servlet://" + SEARCH_REQUEST)
            .process(exchange -> {
                FsiRequest request = createRequestMap(exchange);
                sendRequestToAllProviderRoutes(exchange, request);
            })
            .transform()
            .constant("OK");
}

private void sendRequestToAllProviderRoutes(Exchange exchange, FsiRequest request) {
    try {
        ProducerTemplate tmpl = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
        routeExecutorPool.execute(() -> getRoutes(exchange).parallelStream().forEach(
                route -> tmpl.sendBody(route, request)
        ));
    } catch (RejectedExecutionException | RuntimeCamelException e) {
        log.error("FSI Servlet failed to send request to provider routes", e);
    }
}
```

`getRoutes()` fetches relevant routes by filtering `exchange.getContext().getRouteDefinitions()`.

`sendBody()` works fine when I use a `HashMap<String, Object>` instead of the FsiRequest class.

Comment: Can you share the source code of  the producerTemplate invocation that generates this kind of exception? Can you also share the source code of the route and the ProducerTemplate declaration?

Comment: @ltsallas  Sure, I've updated the question to cover this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to a bug on our part.  The receiving route had this:

```
.setHeader(SEARCH_ID_KEY, simple("${body[searchId]}"))
```

Switching to `body.searchId` solved the issue.

Comment: could you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76414660/not-found-in-bean-org-apache-camel-converter-stream-inputstreamcache