# not found in bean: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-sql

Have a below script , which is throwing an error :

```
 .log("message: ${body}")
   //message: {"caListID":88186,"ciqWatchListID":706596203}
   .setHeader(KafkaConstants.KEY, simple("${body[caListID]}"))            
    .log("message: ${body[caListID]}")
```

**Error :**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Key: caListID not found in bean: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@686300b6 of type: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache using OGNL path [[caListID]]
```

Comment: @neu242 could you please help on this ?

Comment: The message is pretty clear. The body of the incoming message is an InputStream while you are trying to handle it as a bean in your simple expr

Comment: does it help if you switch to `body.caListID`?